# not passing new values to object that has not been destroyed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 scenes and wish to pass info from one to another. I have created in the first scene a script Constants on an empty game object that retains the data that I wish to save for the next scene.

Here it is:

```
public class Constants : MonoBehaviour {

    public string scratchImageFront;
    public string scratchImageBack;

    void setScratchFront(string _scratchFront)
    {
       scratchImageFront = _scratchFront;
    }

    void setScratchBack(string _scratchBack)
    {   
       scratchImageBack = _scratchBack;
    }

}
```

Before moving to the next scene, I call to not destroy the Constants script:

```
     GameObject constants = GameObject.Find("Constants");
     Constants script;
     script = constants.transform.GetComponentInChildren<Constants>();

     DontDestroyOnLoad(constants);
     Application.LoadLevel("scratch");
```

I then collect the data in my second scene and all is good. after I'm done in my second scene, I go back to my first scene

```
Application.LoadLevel("start");
```

and redo the same steps as I first did, the Constants script doesn't retain the new strings passed to it, it retains the old ones. Why?

I need to destroy the Constants script in my second scene so that everything works as it should, but i don't want this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you have 2 instances of Constants at the end because `LoadLevel("start")`; will create an instance again.

Comment: I have a script I call "the mule" that basically does this. https://gist.github.com/3919639

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a "bootstrap" scene with all things that won't be destroyed. It would be the very first scene. It would call your "start" (that wouldn't have the `Constants`) and you would always load "start" from the subsequent scenes, that is, no new `Constants` would be created since "bootstrap" is always called once, in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is creating a static class; here is a link to the same question on answers.unity: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/334959/not-passing-new-values-to-object-that-has-not-been.html